# Facial Recognition on Raspberry Pi using GoPro

Tags: camera, image

I was wondering if someone can tell me how to process a live video feed on the Pi (B) using a GoPro camera? I understand that there may be processing constraints. Then, I would like to do image recognition on it using a python script.

I have connected the camera to the Pi via the USB port on the camera to the Video port on the board. What would I need to do to see a live video stream?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you wanting software that continually "watches" the image and attempts to locate faces and preform a lookup? if so, the pi is probably too slow and too basic. Or will the user position themselves and then press a button (or something)?

Comment: @Tyson Thanks for your reply. I am trying to do the prior...I understand that it may be too slow...but I still wanted to give it a shot. Can you tell me how to view images from the GoPro camera into the Pi? Do I need to install any drivers for it on the Pi or run a script? Thanks!